# Filtering a Square Wave

Tags: filter-design

I'm looking for information about how to filter a square wave.  I don't want to filter it out, but extract it from the rest of the signal.  Most filtering I've encountered usually only care about a limited segment of a spectrum (low-pass, high-pass, band-pass, band-stop).  I have not seen anything about preserving the harmonics.

I am currently trying to tackle the problem by doing an FFT and removing all the frequencies except the square wave's harmonics.  Then an inverse FFT and I get my isolated square wave.  This works well when the noise is an even multiple of the sample rate (which may be reasonable in this particular situation).  This approach seems excessive.  I'm wondering if there is a better or other solutions.

I'm still a novices when it comes to digital filters.  Most of the time I can solve filtering issues using an average or a basic low-pass FIR.  However I want to learn more.  What other options should I look at?  Algorithm names and/or reading material appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I've closed this question as a duplicate because it seems close to the question and answers linked to.  If it's not, please let me know what else we can help with.  Basically, the idea you're looking for is called "comb filters" (among other names).